# Getting query string value in a class

Tags: c#, email

I want get my query string value in a class. These Code is showing error:

> "Request does not in cuurent context"

Here is my code:

```
public class OEMaster : BaseClass
{
   int id = Request.QueryString["id"];
}

public void send Mail()
{  
    mailMessage +=
     "<b> Your message : <a href='http://www.google.com'?id=>           Accept</a></b>";
}
```

Comment: Even if `Request` was available in the current context, this code wouldn't compile. Classes can not directly contain code.

Answer (score 5):

Request is a  property of the page class so you cannot access it from a normal  class.

You can get the [`HttpRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) anyway via HttpContext.Current

**EDIT:**
You cannot use this directly inside a class, create a separate method

Try this,

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
  {
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    int id = request.QueryString["id"];
  }
```

In Order to use HttpContext, Add `System.Web.dll` by right clicking to your **solution explorer -> Add reference**

Comment: Again error showing  "HttpContext.does not exist  in the current context"

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext
//Add System.Web.dll by right clicking to your solution explorer -> Add reference

Comment: This code does not compile. Classes can not contain code directly.